# Python set intersection and neutral top/greatest element

Tags: python, set, mathematical-lattices

Does python have a neutral set (**⊤**, in terms of being the neutral element of intersection) or sort of lattice top/greatest set that works with [basic python sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#module-sets)?

What I mean is the following

```
{1,2,3} & topset
```

simply returns `{1,2,3}` and

```
{1,2,3} | topset
```

returns `topset`.

(Also I would be happy if you could direct me to an older post if this question has already been asked, but I can't find any)

Comment: What do you mean by 'neutral element of intersection'? In this case `topset` can be a superset or `{1,2,3}` itself.

Comment: I meant as a neutral element for *arbitrary* sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website 'Trails in a Langscape' contains an implementation of a [universal set](http://fiber-space.de/wordpress/2009/04/16/universal-set-in-python/). You might want to use that implementation, or extract contents that you need for your implementation.

Basically what they do is implement operator-functions (such as `__radd__`, `__add__`, etc...).

Comment: I don't see license attached to the code, so it's copyright protected?

Comment: True, you might want to contact the person who wrote it, if missing.